# how can I convert day of year to date in javascript?

Tags: javascript, date

I want to take a day of the year and convert to an actual date using the Date object.  Example: day 257 of 1929, how can I go about doing this?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

> "I want to take a day of the year and convert to an actual date using the Date object."

After re-reading your question, it sounds like you have a year number, and an arbitrary day number (e.g. a number within `0..365` (or 366 for a leap year)), and you want to get a date from that.

For example:

```
dateFromDay(2010, 301); // "Thu Oct 28 2010", today ;)
dateFromDay(2010, 365); // "Fri Dec 31 2010"
```

If it's that, can be done easily:

```
function dateFromDay(year, day){
  var date = new Date(year, 0); // initialize a date in `year-01-01`
  return new Date(date.setDate(day)); // add the number of days
}
```

You could add also some validation, to ensure that the day number is withing the range of days in the year supplied.

Comment: setDate() only accepts month numbers 0-30, so I think people have been upvoting this without testing it fully. Look at my answer at the bottom to see an alternative function. (I have a bart simpson avatar)

Comment: It is correct according to the doc: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_setdate.asp "If the month has 31 days: 32 will result in the first day of the next month"

Comment: Or even shorter: `return new Date(year, 0, day)`. ;-)

Comment: As @med116 says -- test carefully.  I got some pretty weird results using this answer.

Comment: @MitchHaile, it should work, what med116 said is not right. Could you share the weird results? Usually, weird results in date manipulation functions occur due to timezone differences.

Comment: @CMS Interesting... using 2019 and a day of 158, I was getting a result that was in October vs June.  This was with Chrome on Mac... of course, testing it now in a solo HTML file, it works, so perhaps there's something more subtle going on with the large app that I was adding to... anyway, like I said, test carefully :-)

Answer (score 8):

The shortest possible way is to create a new date object with the given year, January as month and your day of the year as date:

```js
const date = new Date(2017, 0, 365);

console.log(date.toLocaleDateString());
```

As for `setDate` the correct month gets calculated if the given date is larger than the month's length.

Answer (score 5):

// You might need both parts of it-

```
Date.fromDayofYear= function(n, y){
    if(!y) y= new Date().getFullYear();
    var d= new Date(y, 0, 1);
    return new Date(d.setMonth(0, n));
}
Date.prototype.dayofYear= function(){
    var d= new Date(this.getFullYear(), 0, 0);
    return Math.floor((this-d)/8.64e+7);
}

var d=new Date().dayofYear();
//
alert('day#'+d+' is '+Date.fromDayofYear(d).toLocaleDateString())


/*  returned value: (String)
day#301 is Thursday, October 28, 2010
*/
```

Comment: sorry.. meant if I had a specific day of the year. example: lets say its day 232 of year 1995... how can I construct a new Date out of it?

Comment: var d=Date.fromDayofYear(232,1995)

Answer (score 5):

### Here is a function that takes a day number, and returns the date object

#### optionally, it takes a year in YYYY format for parameter 2. If you leave it off, it will default to current year.

```
var getDateFromDayNum = function(dayNum, year){

    var date = new Date();
    if(year){
        date.setFullYear(year);
    }
    date.setMonth(0);
    date.setDate(0);
    var timeOfFirst = date.getTime(); // this is the time in milliseconds of 1/1/YYYY
    var dayMilli = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
    var dayNumMilli = dayNum * dayMilli;
    date.setTime(timeOfFirst + dayNumMilli);
    return date;
}
```

#### OUTPUT

```
// OUTPUT OF DAY 232 of year 1995

var pastDate = getDateFromDayNum(232,1995)
console.log("PAST DATE: " , pastDate);
```

PAST DATE:  Sun Aug 20 1995 09:47:18 GMT-0400 (EDT)

Comment: Warning: this solution has timezone issues.  It will give wrong answers some of the time.

Answer (score 2):

Here's my implementation, which supports fractional days.  The concept is simple: get the Unix timestamp of midnight on the first day of the year, then multiply the desired day by the number of milliseconds in a day.

```js
    /**
     * Converts day of the year to a Unix timestamp
     * @param {Number} dayOfYear 1-365, with support for floats
     * @param {Number} year (optional) 2 or 4 digit year representation. Defaults to
     * current year.
     * @return {Number} Unix timestamp (ms precision)
     */
    function dayOfYearToTimestamp(dayOfYear, year) {
      year = year || (new Date()).getFullYear();
      var dayMS = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;

      // Note the Z, forcing this to UTC time.  Without this it would be a local time, which would have to be further adjusted to account for timezone.
      var yearStart = new Date('1/1/' + year + ' 0:0:0 Z');

      return yearStart + ((dayOfYear - 1) * dayMS);
    }

    // usage

    // 2015-01-01T00:00:00.000Z
    console.log(new Date(dayOfYearToTimestamp(1, 2015)));

    // support for fractional day (for satellite TLE propagation, etc)
    // 2015-06-29T12:19:03.437Z
    console.log(new Date(dayOfYearToTimestamp(180.51323423, 2015)).toISOString);
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you can do that from the Date constructor like this

```
new Date(year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds)
```

All arguments as integers

Answer (score 1):

You have a few options;

If you're using a standard format, you can do something like:

```
new Date(dateStr);
```

If you'd rather be safe about it, you could do:

```
var date, timestamp;
try {
    timestamp = Date.parse(dateStr);
} catch(e) {}
if(timestamp)
    date = new Date(timestamp);

or simply,    

new Date(Date.parse(dateStr));
```

Or, if you have an arbitrary format, split the string/parse it into units, and do:

```
new Date(year, month - 1, day)
```

Example of the last:

```
var dateStr = '28/10/2010'; // uncommon US short date
var dateArr = dateStr.split('/');
var dateObj = new Date(dateArr[2], parseInt(dateArr[1]) - 1, dateArr[0]);
```

Comment: sorry.. meant if I had a specific day of the year. example: lets say its day 232 of year 1995... how can I construct a new Date out of it?

Answer (score 0):

this also works ..

```
function to2(x) { return ("0"+x).slice(-2); }
function formatDate(d){
    return d.getFullYear()+"-"+to2(d.getMonth()+1)+"-"+to2(d.getDate());
    }
document.write(formatDate(new Date(2016,0,257)));
```

prints "2016-09-13"

which is correct as 2016 is a leaap year. (see calendars here: http://disc.sci.gsfc.nasa.gov/julian_calendar.html )

Answer (score 0):

If you **always** want a **UTC** date:

```js
function getDateFromDayOfYear (year, day) {
  return new Date(Date.UTC(year, 0, day))
}

console.log(getDateFromDayOfYear(2020, 1)) // 2020-01-01T00:00:00.000Z
console.log(getDateFromDayOfYear(2020, 305)) // 2020-10-31T00:00:00.000Z
console.log(getDateFromDayOfYear(2020, 366)) // 2020-12-31T00:00:00.000Z
```