# Convert day of the year to a date in java

Tags: java, sql, date

I have a number of day of the year. (Today's number of the day is 308.) I want to convert this number to a date in SQL format (`YYYY/MM/DD`). Can I do it in java?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) for example has a format `D`, which represents the day in the year. You could simply parse it to a `Date` by providing the number

Comment: There's no such thing as a SQL format, or a date format at all. Dates are stored as *binary* values in all databases. Formats apply only when you cast the dates from/to strings, or if you store the date as a string instead of an actual date-typed value

Comment: The ANSI SQL date format is YYYY-MM-DD. But you want to it in Java?

Comment: @Asjon if your database field is date-typed, there's no reason to convert the date to string. Just calculate the current `Date` and store it to the database *as a date*.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, how the date values are stored on disk is unimportant. The SQL standard has a specified date format. (However, some dbms products do things their own way...)

Comment: Which version of Java are you using?

Comment: @jarlh no it doesn't. What you are talking about is the ISO 8601 *date literal*, not a date format. Date values should not be passed as strings at all. All data access libraries allow you to pass strongly-typed parameters to parameterized queries

Comment: you can refer this page: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4048688/how-can-i-convert-day-of-year-to-date-in-javascript

Answer (score 6):

## tl;dr

```
Year.of( 2018 )
    .atDay( 308 )
```

> 2018-11-04

## java.time

The modern approach uses the java.time classes built into Java 8 and later.

The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone.

The [`Year`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/Year.html) class represents, well, a year. And includes a [`atDay( dayOfYear )`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/Year.html#atDay-int-) method where you pass your ordinal day of the year.

```
int dayOfYear = 308 ;
Year y = Year.of( 2018 ) ;
LocalDate ld = y.atDay( dayOfYear ) ;
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println( "dayOfYear: " + dayOfYear + " at year: " + y + " = " + ld ) ;
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://www.ideone.com/3bdHBN).

> dayOfYear: 308 at year: 2018 = 2018-11-04

As for generating a string in a particular format, search for `DateTimeFormatter` class as that has been covered many many times already.

And by the way, your particular format is not at all a “SQL format”. Regardless, you should be exchanging objects with your database rather than mere strings. Look at the `getObject` and `setObject` methods in JDBC when using a driver compliant with JDBC 4.2 or later.

## Database

For SQL access to a database column of SQL-standard type `DATE`, use JDBC 4.2 or later to pass the `LocalDate` object directly. Do not use mere strings to exchange date-time values.

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , ld ) ;
```

Retrieval.

```
LocalDate ld = myResultSet.getDate( … , LocalDate.class ) ;
```

[image: Table of date-time types in Java (both modern and legacy) and in standard SQL.]

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Comment: Basil, the references are gold. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

```
int dayOfYear = 112;
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, dayOfYear);
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY/MM/dd");
System.out.println("Day of year " + dayOfYear + " = " + sdf.format(calendar.getTime()));
```

hope above snippets helps you

Comment: Thanks for the answer,i'll try this and i'll let you know if it helps!

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 & Java 9. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).