# get the date by using the year and day number in the year

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have a function for which I get the year and day number of that year as arguments and I need to return the date. I have tried using momentjs but not able to fetch correct results. suppose getDate(2019,1) should return `Jan 1, 2019` or `1st Jan 2019` date format doesn't matter. any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Try with - `moment().format("MMM D, YYYY")`  ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how can I convert day of year to date in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4048688/how-can-i-convert-day-of-year-to-date-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using momentjs was a good idea.

```
function getDate(year, dayOfYear) {
    return moment().dayOfYear(dayOfYear).year(year)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look at [mometJs](https://momentjs.com/) library. There are multiple examples given.

If you already haven't implemented momentJs i would suggest you have a look at [day.Js](https://day.js.org/) it is much lightweight compared to momentJs.